# The function idr_alloc(...) fails sometimes with the error -EINVAL(-22)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying out the Kernel API for IDR (Integer ID Management). It's a map where an ID get's associated with a pointer.
The API has changed, so old examples that i found, didn't work.
So i did my own example and it works only partially.
Sometimes the function idr_alloc fails with -22(-EINVAL).

When i looked at the implementation source code(https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source), i found out, that the only error's are (-ENOMEM, no memory and -ENOSPC(No more ID's).
I complile my code against : Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-33-generic.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/idr.h>

struct idr map;

char *cptr1 = "Chennai";
char *cptr2 = "Lockheed Martin";
char *cptr3 = "Libary";

int deleter (int id, void *ptr, void *data ) {
    idr_remove( &map, id );
    return 0;
}

int showKeyValuePair( int id, void *ptr, void *data ) {
    printk("Key : %d | Value : %s\n", id, (char *)ptr );
    return 0;
}

static int __init mod_init(void)        
{                                                                   
    int id[3];
    char *ptr;

    printk("IDR\n");    
    idr_init( &map );       

    id[0] = idr_alloc( &map, (void *)cptr1, 0, 0, GFP_KERNEL );
    id[1] = idr_alloc( &map, (void *)cptr2, 0, 0, GFP_KERNEL );
    id[2] = idr_alloc( &map, (void *)cptr3, 0, 0, GFP_KERNEL );

    printk("Reserved ID's : {%d, %d, %d}\n", id[0], id[1], id[2] );

    ptr = idr_find( &map, id[0] );
    printk("Find for ID %d = %s\n", id[0], (ptr != NULL) ? ptr : "not found" );


    idr_for_each( &map, showKeyValuePair, NULL );

    return 0;
}

static void __exit mod_exit(void) 
{
    idr_for_each( &map, deleter, NULL );    
    idr_destroy( &map );        // void idr_destroy (struct idr *)
}

module_init(mod_init);  
module_exit(mod_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found out that the implementation in Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-33-generic was buggy. I compiled my code against the Kernel Source Tree version 4.9.0-8-amd64 and it worked out.
The code -EINVAL get returned when start, the third parameter of idr_alloc is smaller then 0, but that was not the case, but idr_alloc calls idr_alloc_cmn in the old version and this probably returned -EINVAL. I can't find the implementation of idr_alloc_cmn, but the most important thing: It works now.